# How do I group by hour in SparkR?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am trying to summarize some dates by their hour, using SparkR and Spark 2.1.0.
My data looks like:

```
                       created_at
1  Sun Jul 31 22:25:01 +0000 2016
2  Sun Jul 31 22:25:01 +0000 2016
3  Fri Jun 03 10:16:57 +0000 2016
4  Mon May 30 19:23:55 +0000 2016
5  Sat Jun 11 21:00:07 +0000 2016
6  Tue Jul 12 16:31:46 +0000 2016
7  Sun May 29 19:12:26 +0000 2016
8  Sat Aug 06 11:04:29 +0000 2016
9  Sat Aug 06 11:04:29 +0000 2016
10 Sat Aug 06 11:04:29 +0000 2016
```

and I want the output to be:

```
Hour      Count
22         2
10         1
19         1
11         3
....
```

I tried:

```
sumdf <- summarize(groupBy(df, df$created_at), count = n(df$created_at))
head(select(sumdf, "created_at", "count"),10)
```

but that groups to the nearest second:

```
                       created_at count
1  Sun Jun 12 10:24:54 +0000 2016     1
2  Tue Aug 09 14:12:35 +0000 2016     2
3  Fri Jul 29 19:22:03 +0000 2016     2
4  Mon Jul 25 21:05:05 +0000 2016     2
```

I tried:

```
sumdf <- summarize(groupBy(df, hr=hour(df$created_at)), count = n(hour(df$created_at)))
head(select(sumdf, "hour(created_at)", "count"),20)
```

but that gives:

```
  hour(created_at) count
1               NA     0
```

I tried:

```
sumdf <- summarize(groupBy(df, df$created_at), count = n(hour(df$created_at)))
head(select(sumdf, "created_at", "count"),10)
```

but that gives:

```
                       created_at count
1  Sun Jun 12 10:24:54 +0000 2016     0
2  Tue Aug 09 14:12:35 +0000 2016     0
3  Fri Jul 29 19:22:03 +0000 2016     0
4  Mon Jul 25 21:05:05 +0000 2016     0
...
```

How can I use the hour function to achieve this, or is there a better way?

Comment: You should try to split your `created_at` column into `hour` values and then use groupBy on the `hour` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your local table is `df`, the real problem here is to extract the hour out of your `created_at` column and then use your grouping code. To do this, you can use `dapply`:

```
library(SparkR)
sc1 <- sparkR.session()
df2 <- createDataFrame(df)

#with dapply you need to specify the schema i.e. the data.frame that will come out
#of the applied function - i.e. substringDF in our case
schema <- structType(structField('created_at', 'string'), structField('time', 'string'))

#a function that will be applied to each partition of the spark data frame.
#remember that each partition is a data.frame itself.
substringDF <- function(DF) {

 DF$time <- substr(DF$created_at, 15, 16)

 DF

}

#and then we use the above in dapply
df3 <- dapply(df2, substringDF, schema)
head(df3)
#                        created_at time
#1 1  Sun Jul 31 22:25:01 +0000 2016   22
#2 2  Sun Jul 31 22:25:01 +0000 2016   22
#3 3  Fri Jun 03 10:16:57 +0000 2016   10
#4 4  Mon May 30 19:23:55 +0000 2016   19
#5 5  Sat Jun 11 21:00:07 +0000 2016   21
#6 6  Tue Jul 12 16:31:46 +0000 2016   16
```

Then just apply your normal grouping code:

```
sumdf <- summarize(groupBy(df3, df3$time), count = n(df3$time))
head(select(sumdf, "time", "count"))
#  time count
#1   11     3
#2   22     2
#3   16     1
#4   19     2
#5   10     1
#6   21     1
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned I am using Spark 1.6.3 and I do not think dapply exists for that.

Comment: I have decided to use Spark2 and give your solution a go. df is a spark data frame already. So I use your code minus the forst 3 lines and change df2 to df and df3 to df2. The `head(df3)` gives: `ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 12)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUti` any ideas?

Comment: If you changed my `df3` to `df2` you should use `head(df2)` right? Also, try using my code as it is to see if it works (i.e. name your spark data.frame df2). I tried this on both a standalone version and a YARN version and they both work fine. Are you sure Spark 2 was installed and configured correctly?

Comment: Yes `head(df2)`. I think Spark2 is OK, been using it for a while. This works well: `head(substringDF(df))`. I will try restarting Spark2.

Comment: Therefore, it might be a case of the schema. You need to tell `dapply` what the structure of the sparkdata.frame will be i.e. it needs to know the column names and the data types of the columns (e.g. column name `time` as a `string` in the above case). Make sure you have set those correctly.

Comment: Yes I had another column in df. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

I'd parse the date with `to_timestamp` (Spark 2.2) or `unix_timestamp %>% cast("timestamp")` (earlier version) and access the `hour`:

```
df <- createDataFrame(data.frame(created_at="Sat Aug 19 12:33:26 +0000 2017"))
head(count(group_by(df, 
  alias(hour(to_timestamp(column("created_at"), "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy")), "hour")
)))
##  hour count
## 1   14     1
```

Comment: Thanks. I have made a few changes as I use 1.6.3: df <- createDataFrame(data.frame(created_at="Sat Aug 19 12:33:26 +0000 2017"))
head(count(groupBy(df, 
                    alias(hour(unix_timestamp(column("dt.gmt"), "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy") %>% cast("timestamp")), "hour")
))) Any idea how to overcome: Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz(x)) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code SCALA, I think you can refer it.

```
    var index = ss.sparkContext.parallelize( Seq(
  (1,"Sun Jul 31 22:25:01 +0000 2016"),
  (2,"Sun Jul 31 22:25:01 +0000 2016"),
  (3,"Fri Jun 03 10:16:57 +0000 2016"),
  (4,"Mon May 30 19:23:55 +0000 2016"),
  (5,"Sat Jun 11 21:00:07 +0000 2016"),
  (6,"Tue Jul 12 16:31:46 +0000 2016"),
  (7,"Sun May 29 19:12:26 +0000 2016"),
  (8,"Sat Aug 06 11:04:29 +0000 2016"),
  (9,"Sat Aug 06 11:04:29 +0000 2016"),
  (10,"Sat Aug 06 11:04:29 +0000 2016"))
).toDF("ID", "time")

val getHour = udf( (s : String) => {
  s.substring( 11, 13)
})
index.withColumn("hour", getHour($"time")).groupBy( "hour").agg( count("*").as("count")).show
```

Comment: This is off topic and even for Scala it's bad practice. I believe the OP was precise about sparkR

Comment: Yes, so I said "Here is code SCALA, I think you can refer it."

Comment: This is still bad code @Robin . One should accept criticism. I didn't insult you as I recall. I didn't downvote you might others might.

Comment: I don't understand SparkR, I know a little Scala. SO I put my idea here and hope to give some inspiration to asker.

Comment: That's not the issue. But if you want a review of your Scala code, here it is : treating dates as string is bad practice. You should use date libraries and parsers in case the format changes.

Comment: I see, I tried the  sql function name hour directly as below but failed.              index.withColumn("hour", hour($"time")).groupBy( "hour").agg( count("*").as("count")).show                  Perhaps we can format the "time" column and then use the "hour" function.